# Instantiate score flash at a specific position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am facing now a problem that I hope that you can help me solve it. I have a space shooter game where I added score flash once you destroy a `gameobject`. The thing I want to correct is that I don't know how to spawn the score flash at the place where the `gameobject` was destroyed. It is spawning always in one place where I have set it to `spawn` but I want it to spawn always at the place where the `gameobject` gets destroyed.
Here is the code:

```
public GameObject explosion, spawnItem;
public GameObject playerExplosion;
private Done_GameController gameController;
private PlayerHealth playerhealth;
public Text ScoreFlash;
public GameObject canvasg;
public int scoreValue;
public float lifetime;

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Boundary" || other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        return;
    }
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet") 
    {
        playerhealth.AddScore (scoreValue);
        Destroy (gameObject);
        scoreflash ();
    }
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" || other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet") 
    {
        Instantiate (explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }
    if (CheckIfAsteroid (transform.tag, 3) == "Ast" && other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet") 
    {
        Instantiate (spawnItem, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
string CheckIfAsteroid(string tag, int index)
{
    Debug.Log (tag.Substring (0, Mathf.Min (tag.Length, index)));
    return tag.Substring (0, Mathf.Min (tag.Length, index));
}
    void scoreflash()
{
    ScoreFlash.text = " +" + scoreValue + "p";
    Text newtext = Instantiate(ScoreFlash) as Text;
    GameObject newcanvas = Instantiate (canvasg) as GameObject;
    newtext.transform.SetParent (newcanvas.transform,false);
    Destroy (newcanvas,lifetime);
}
```

So the `scoreflash` function is the function that instantiates the text with the needed value and the string Check if asteroid part is for the instantiation of a gameobject. Where the gameobject will be instantiated there the text needs to appear. I have deleted a part of the hole code because it is not important. Please Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to spawn the score flash at the place where the
>   gameobject was destroyed

Get the position of that GameObject before destroying it then call the scoreflash function and pass in the position into it.

Replace the `OnTriggerEnter` and `scoreflash` function with the new function below. You may need to modify it to work correctly but this should get you started.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Boundary" || other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        return;
    }
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        playerhealth.AddScore(scoreValue);

        //Get position before destryoing gameobject
        Vector3 diedPos = gameObject.transform.position;
        Destroy(gameObject);
        scoreflash(diedPos);
    }
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" || other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    if (CheckIfAsteroid(transform.tag, 3) == "Ast" && other.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        Instantiate(spawnItem, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

void scoreflash(Vector3 diedPosition)
{
    ScoreFlash.text = " +" + scoreValue + "p";
    Text newtext = Instantiate(ScoreFlash) as Text;
    GameObject newcanvas = Instantiate(canvasg) as GameObject;
    newtext.transform.SetParent(newcanvas.transform, false);

    Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(diedPosition);
    newtext.transform.position = screenPos;
    Destroy(newcanvas, lifetime);
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks let me try and I will tell you if it works

Comment: So I just tried it, it doesn't work but I understand why I think, the text I have given it a rect transform maybe that is why it is appearing always in one place may be I should give 000 rect transform or stretch?

Comment: you left many things out. Is the Object that is getting destroyed 2d(Sprite) or 3d object(Mesh)? Is your canvas set to screen space or world? These information are required to help you.

Comment: oh cool you answered, the objects are 3d, the canvas is set to size after the screen size,

Comment: screen space overlay

Comment: if you want, only if you want you can help via team viewer, just if you want

Comment: You need to convert the position of the destroyed GameObject to a screen-space with `Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint` then move the text to that location. I updated the `scoreflash` function. Take a look at it. Let me know if there is still a problem.

Comment: So thanks for help but there is still a problem, but now there are somechanges, first spawns the text and canvas where I have set it but I have st it to be stretch and then another one lower and not always

Comment: i just changed false to true and now it is spawning wher eit is needed that is so cool thanks for your help

Comment: Nice. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the position of the collision and set the transform of your score flash to be that.

I apologize that I can't currently access Unity to get the specific syntax that you need, but that's your issue. Nowhere do you tell Unity where it should be placing this new object, so if I had to guess it appears at 0.0.0 since that's a pretty normal 'default'.